# What happened in JasperStudio to the class WizardDataSourcePage?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

After the upgrade of JasperSoft Studio from version 5.6.1 to 6.3.1 the class WizardDataSourcePage is missing.

The class seems to be removed, but there is no information about it anywhere. Neither what the methods inside this class did before or if the JasperSoft team moved the functionality to another class (like StaticWizardDataSourcePage).

Do somebody have some kind of information about it or can give a hint?

Comment: Already tried out: Analyzed their sources, but they provide it only until version 6.0.0. Asked in their user forum, but got no answer.

Comment: You can try to start search over [source code](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jaspersoftstudio/branches/)

Comment: @AlexK - I pulled their sources, but they provide it only down to version 6.0.0 and not until 5.6.1. Or did I miss there something?